# python matplotlib update scatter plot from a function

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to automatically update a scatter plot.
The source of my X and Y values is external, and the data is pushed automatically into my code in a non-predicted time intervals (rounds).

I have only managed to plot all the data when the whole process ended, whereas I am trying to constantly add and plot data into my canvas.

What I DO get (at the end of the whole run) is this:
[image]

Whereas, what I am after is this:
[image]

A simplified version of my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def read_data():
    #This function gets the values of xAxis and yAxis
    xAxis = [some values]  #these valuers change in each run
    yAxis = [other values] #these valuers change in each run

    plt.scatter(xAxis,yAxis, label  = 'myPlot', color = 'k', s=50)     
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are several ways to animate a matplotlib plot. In the following let's look at two minimal examples using a scatter plot.

#### (a) use interactive mode `plt.ion()`

For an animation to take place we need an event loop. One way of getting the event loop is to use `plt.ion()` ("interactive on"). One then needs to first draw the figure and can then update the plot in a loop. Inside the loop, we need to draw the canvas and introduce a little pause for the window to process other events (like the mouse interactions etc.). Without this pause the window would freeze. Finally we call `plt.waitforbuttonpress()` to let the window stay open even after the animation has finished.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x, y = [],[]
sc = ax.scatter(x,y)
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,10)

plt.draw()
for i in range(1000):
    x.append(np.random.rand(1)*10)
    y.append(np.random.rand(1)*10)
    sc.set_offsets(np.c_[x,y])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    plt.pause(0.1)

plt.waitforbuttonpress()
```

#### (b) using `FuncAnimation`

Much of the above can be automated using [`matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html). The FuncAnimation will take care of the loop and the redrawing and will constantly call a function (in this case `animate()`) after a given time interval. The animation will only start once `plt.show()` is called, thereby automatically running in the plot window's event loop.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x, y = [],[]
sc = ax.scatter(x,y)
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,10)

def animate(i):
    x.append(np.random.rand(1)*10)
    y.append(np.random.rand(1)*10)
    sc.set_offsets(np.c_[x,y])

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 
                frames=2, interval=100, repeat=True) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't know how I could have gone this long and never known about `ion`. +1

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. By far the clearest of all dealing with this issue!

Comment: Oddly, the assignment to `ani` is required for (b) to work.  Can you explain this magic?

Comment: @Alan The rough explanation is simply: If you have a class `SomeClass` and instantiate it via `SomeClass(argument1, argument2, etc)` it will be gone in the moment its `__init__` method returns. If you need that instance for anything later on (and you will in case of an animation running at some point later in time), you need to store it in a variable, such that it is kept in memory, `myinstance = SomeClass(...)`

Answer (score 8):

From what I understand, you want to update interactively your plot. If so, you can use plot instead of scatter plot and update the data of your plot like this.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
fig = plt.figure()
axe = fig.add_subplot(111)
X,Y = [],[]
sp, = axe.plot([],[],label='toto',ms=10,color='k',marker='o',ls='')
fig.show()
for iter in range(5):
    X.append(numpy.random.rand())
    Y.append(numpy.random.rand())
    sp.set_data(X,Y)
    axe.set_xlim(min(X),max(X))
    axe.set_ylim(min(Y),max(Y))
    raw_input('...')
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

If this is the behaviour your are looking for, you just need to create a function appending the data of sp, and get in that function the new points you want to plot (either with I/O management or whatever the communication process you're using).
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem to work fully. Instead of plotting the data in each round of data collection - I get a blank canvas as long as the code runs, and once it finishes running - I get all the data at the same time (i.e., the top image in my question).

Comment: @aTben0 I wonder in which environment this solution would work as it's clearly missing an event loop.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest As the posted issue is tagged as matplotlib and scatter-plot I was thinking about an I/O management which would wait for a file to be updated and then append X and Y as soon as the file is modified. If so, I don't see why the interactive mode is needed, or do I miss something? Anyway, thanks for your complete answer and comment.

Comment: You miss the event loop and the interactive mode is one way of obtaining it.

Comment: This won't work if you want to have a 3d plot. If you create plot like `sp, = axe.plot([],[], [])` and use `sp.set_data([], [], [])`, you'll get an error since it is a `2DLine`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of creating an interactive plot in Jupyter notebook

```
# Import Libraries

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

# Create figure and subplot

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1) 

# Define and update plot

for i in range(20):
    x = np.linspace(0, i, 100);
    y = np.cos(x) 
    ax.set_xlim(0, i)    
    ax.cla()
    ax.plot(x, y)
    display(fig)    
    clear_output(wait = True)
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

This will update the same plot iteratively. A detailed description is given here https://pythonguides.com/matplotlib-update-plot-in-loop/