# How can I continue to make a scatter plot after plt.show()

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have made some scatter plot and show it, but after that, I want to show my drawing process by redrawing those scatter plot with another color.

I want to dynamic show the process of drawing.
How can I do that ??

I add the `ax.scatter()` after `plt.show()`, but it doesn't works.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.scatter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],marker=".")
plt.grid(ls=':')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to turn on interactive mode: https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode

Comment: Thank you ,I saw your advice, I think it's useful,  this document show me the the way to do it in  terminal, but terminal command line is unresponsive. How can I do it in python file ?

Comment: I think you are looking for an animation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722691/python-matplotlib-update-scatter-plot-from-a-function). If this solves the problem, one can close as duplicate, otherwise please refine your question to explicitely tell in how far this is different.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are the perfect solution to my problem。