# How to use a point to describe the trail of an object with package matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, point, path-finding

In the while loop,the command `plt.plot(x,y,'*')` paints the trail of an object.SO there are many points painted in the axes. But I just want a moving point to describe the trail.

Details are in the "while loop" of following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#just a dynamic painting
tolerance = 1e-1
radius = np.pi

# missile 1
x_m1, y_m1 = -np.pi, 0
v_m1 = 5

# missile 2
x_m2, y_m2 = 0, np.pi
v_m2 = v_m1
# missile 3
x_m3, y_m3 = np.pi, 0
v_m3 = v_m1
# missile 4
x_m4, y_m4 = 0, -np.pi
v_m4 = v_m1

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=80)
plt.title(" missile flight simulator ", fontsize=40)
plt.xlim(-4, 4)
plt.ylim(-4, 4)
#plt.xticks([])
#plt.yticks([])

# set spines
ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0))


plt.annotate('missile start point', xy=(x_m1, y_m1),  xycoords='data',
             xytext=(+15, +15), textcoords='offset points', fontsize=12,
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", connectionstyle="arc3,rad=.2"))

# alpha labels
for label in ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels():
    label.set_fontsize(16)
    label.set_bbox(dict(facecolor='white', edgecolor='None', alpha=0.65))


class ob(object):
    """docstring for ob"""
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class missile(ob):
    """docstring for missile"""
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(missile, self).__init__(x, y)

    def forward(self, v, target):
        """docstring for forward"""
        if self.x < target.x:
            alpha = np.arctan((target.y - self.y) / (target.x - self.x))
        elif self.x > target.x:
            alpha = np.pi + np.arctan((target.y - self.y) / (target.x - self.x))
        elif self.x == target.x and self.y < target.y:
            alpha = np.pi / 2
        else:
            alpha = -np.pi / 2
        self.x = self.x + v * 0.01 * np.cos(alpha)
        self.y = self.y + v * 0.01 * np.sin(alpha)
        return self.x, self.y

    def distance(self, target):
        """docstring for distance"""
        return np.sqrt((self.x - target.x) ** 2 + (self.y - target.y) ** 2)


class target(ob):
    """docstring for target"""
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(target, self).__init__(x, y)

    def newposition(self, x, y):
        """docstring for newposition"""
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

m1 = missile(x_m1, y_m1)
m2 = missile(x_m2, y_m2)
m3 = missile(x_m3, y_m3)
m4 = missile(x_m4, y_m4)

while True: #details
#just a dynamic painting
    if m1.distance(m2) < tolerance or m1.distance(m3) < tolerance or m1.distance(m4) < tolerance:    #In the loop,many points are painted to discribe the trail    
        print "collision"
        plt.plot(x_m1, y_m1, 'o')
        plt.annotate('crash point', xy=(x_m1, y_m1),  xycoords='data',
                     xytext=(+15, +15), textcoords='offset points', fontsize=12,
                     arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", connectionstyle="arc3,rad=.2"))
        plt.pause(0.1)
        plt.show()
        break
    elif m3.distance(m2) < tolerance or m3.distance(m4) < tolerance:
        print "collision"
        plt.plot(x_m3, y_m3, 'o')
        plt.annotate('crash point', xy=(x_m3, y_m3),  xycoords='data',
                     xytext=(+15, +15), textcoords='offset points', fontsize=12,
                     arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", connectionstyle="arc3,rad=.2"))
        plt.pause(0.1)
        plt.show
        break
    x_m1, y_m1 = m1.forward(v_m1, m2)
    x_m2, y_m2 = m2.forward(v_m2, m3)
    x_m3, y_m3 = m3.forward(v_m3, m4)
    x_m4, y_m4 = m4.forward(v_m4, m1)
    #print alpha, beta
    plt.plot(x_m1, y_m1, 'bx', alpha=.5)
    plt.plot(x_m2, y_m2, 'k*', alpha=.5)
    plt.plot(x_m3, y_m3, 'r.', alpha=.5)
    plt.plot(x_m4, y_m4, 'gp', alpha=.5)
    plt.legend(("missile1", "missile2", "missile3", "missile4"), loc="upper left", prop={'size': 12})

    plt.pause(0.1)
```

Are there any resolution given? This program is just for dynamic painting... aka paint a moving point to show the track of an object. The point's coordinate get updated with its regular speed. In my code, all points of the track are painted, but I only need one moving point. Just like an running car in the road, every time you see one moving car in a different place of the track. You can delete the "while" loop, if you could use other ways to achieve my expectation.

Comment: "Details are in the while loop" doesn't provide enough information for anyone to be able to assist you. What do you mean "i just want a moving point to discribe the trail"? Please boil down your problem to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (keyword in **minimal** here)

Comment: Paint a moving point to show the track of an object.The point's  coordinate get updated with its regular speed. In my codes,all points of the track are painted,but i only need one moving point.Just like an running car in the road,everytime  you see one moving car in different place of the track

Comment: You can delete the "while" loop,if you could use other ways to achieve my expectation.

Comment: There are two ways of producing an animation as shown e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722691/python-matplotlib-update-scatter-plot-from-a-function). Choose a method, stick to it and you should directly get the desired plot. It doesn't matter if you update your plot with a single point or multiple points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understood your question, but:

It looks like you've fallen into the same trap as 90% of people asking about animations and matplotlib, in that you are repeatedly calling `plot()` at each step of your iterations, thus creating new points (really, new `Line2D` objects) at each steps, instead of updating the properties of the existing one.

The general procedure for animations is to:

1. create your figure and all the fixed elements that do not need to be updated
2. create the artists that need to be updated, **and keep a reference to them**
3. in your loop, **update** (instead of replacing or creating new artists) the properties of the artists created in the previous step.

Since you did not get my hint about creating a *minimal* working example, let me show that 99% of your code was useless and that your problem can be simplified and solved just like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
# create a placeholder artist object, and keep a reference to it
my_line, = plt.plot([], [], 'bx', alpha=.5)
plt.legend(["my line"], loc="upper left", prop={'size': 12})
plt.xlim([0, 10])
plt.ylim([0, 10])
i = 0

while True:
    # do whatever to get next coordinates
    i = (i + 1) % 10
    new_x, new_y = i, i
    # update artist
    my_line.set_data(new_x, new_y)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

Finally, I will echo @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's comment and suggest you look into [the FuncAnimation module](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html?highlight=funcanimation) to produce your animations, although the overall strategy remains exactly the same.

Comment: Yeah，you completely get my point.This resolution is perfect for me.

Comment: When i  turned to matplotlib helping document  for resolution, the command "set_data"  was always  seen.But hardly i link it with my problem.Besides,i am very familiar to "plt.plot()".However,i have never thought creating an object  like"my_line".  Could you give some suggestion about looking for helping document or opening mind in programing.

Comment: The document means matplotlib.It's too brief in some aspect  to find usage of some function and properties

Comment: Are there any methods to stop the moving point "my_line" showing again,after some running time