# Matplotlib toggle between points in plot with keyboard

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 3D scatter plot in matplotlib plotted as `ax.scatter(xyz[:, 0], xyz[:, 1], xyz[:, 2], c=xyz_rgb)`. Let's say I have two lists of indices, `mask_1` and `mask_2` such that these are a subset of points in `xyz`. I want to be able to plot all of `xyz`, then use a keyboard press to toggle between `xyz[:,:]`, `xyz[mask_1,:]` and `xyz[mask_2,:]`. Is this doable? If so, how would I achieve that? The problematic part isn't capturing the keyboard events, but actually toggling the visibility of points in a plot.

Comment: I would have guessed the problematic part is the key capture if anything. Visibility can be done via `set_visible(False)` (or `True`).

Comment: I'm not interested in drawing 3 separate figures and hiding them based on input. I want to have one figure in which points are toggled. So that the camera perspective, etc. is preserved.

Comment: if you have 3 plots `points1`, `points2`,  `points3`, you can do `plot1.set_visible(False)` to hide points1. Alternatively you can work with a single `points1` and update its data.

Comment: The 3 plot one won't work for the reason I stated. How do I go about updating the data of an existing plot?

Comment: Both will work. For updating a scatter see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722691/python-matplotlib-update-scatter-plot-from-a-function).