# Particle swarm of 2D function in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like:

1. A plot with a function :  [f(x,y) -> (x² + y²)/20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPPzp.png)
2. A set of points (x, y, f(x,y)) that evolve over time.

To solve this problem I tried to clear the plot and update it at each iteration but I did not manage to do it...

Here's my code:

```
def parabole(x, y):
    return (x * x + y * y)/10

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 30)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 30)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = parabole(X, Y)
for swarm in history:
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='jet', edgecolor='none')
    for particle in swarm:
         ax.scatter(particle[0], particle[1], particle[2])
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()
```

`history` is a list containing different state of my particle swarm.
My particle swarm is a list of points (x, y, f(x,y))

How do I clear a plot at each iteration of the loop, and then plot the whole thing again in the same figure?

Comment: are you trying to make an animation? https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html

Comment: If I got your question correctly, you can do it following the answers here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/42722691/python-matplotlib-update-scatter-plot-from-a-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722691/python-matplotlib-update-scatter-plot-from-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

First you should take this line outside of the loop:

  fig = plt.figure()

Secondly, instead using these two lines:

 plt.show()

 plt.clf()

you should use:

 fig.canvas.draw()

 fig.canvas.flush_events()

Also, add this line to run GUI event loop: (You can also look at the link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-update-a-plot-on-same-figure-during-the-loop/)

  plt.ion()

**Finally your code should look line this:**

def parabole(x, y):

   return (x * x + y * y)/10


x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 30)

y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 30)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = parabole(X, Y)


plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure()


for swarm in history:

    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='jet', edgecolor='none')

    for particle in swarm:

          ax.scatter(particle[0], particle[1], particle[2])

   fig.canvas.draw()

   fig.canvas.flush_events()

  time.sleep(0.1) # You can also add this to observe the changes